# Exceptions or null in java

Tags: java, exception, null, wrapper, signature

I have the next doubt. According to good practices of java, how to manage the cases in which the object can not be found and we want to know why.

For example, if someone has problems logging in our system and we want to inform them exactly what is the problem, we cannot return null because we lose the reason for not being able to log in. For example:

```
public User login(String username, String password) {
    boolean usernameEmpty = (credentials.getUsername()==null || credentials.getUsername().isEmpty());
    boolean passwordEmpty = (credentials.getPassword()==null || credentials.getPassword().isEmpty());
    //getUserPassword return null if doesn't exist an user with username and password return null
    User user = getUserPassword(username,password);

    if (!usernameEmpty && !passwordEmpty && user!=null) {
        LOGGER.info("Found " + username);
    } else if (!usernameEmpty && !passwordEmpty && user==null) {
        LOGGER.info("There is no such username and password: " + username);
    } else if (usernameEmpty) {
        LOGGER.info("Username can not be empty ");
    } else if (passwordEmpty) {
        LOGGER.info("Password can not be empty ");
    }

    return user;
}
```

I can think of two options with pros and cons to resolve it.

The **first** one consists in using Exceptions but I think that is not a good idea use different scenarios than expected like exceptions. For that reason, I discard it.

The **second** one is involve the object (User) in another object to manage the differents posibilities. For example, use something like this:

```
public class EntityObject<t> {
    //Is used to return the entity or entities if everything was fine
    private t entity;
    //Is used to inform of any checked exception
    private String exceptionMessage;

    //getters / setters / ..
}

public EntityObject<User> login(String username, String password) {
    boolean usernameEmpty = (credentials.getUsername()==null || credentials.getUsername().isEmpty());
    boolean passwordEmpty = (credentials.getPassword()==null || credentials.getPassword().isEmpty());
    User user = getUserPassword(username,password);
    EntityObject<User> entity = null;

    if (!usernameEmpty && !passwordEmpty && user!=null) {
        LOGGER.info("Found " + username);
        entity = new EntityObject<User>(user);
    } else if (!usernameEmpty && !passwordEmpty && user==null) {
        entity = new EntityObject<User>("There is no such username and password: " + username); 
    } else if (usernameEmpty) {
        entity = new EntityObject<User>("Username can not be empty ");
    } else if (passwordEmpty) {
        entity = new EntityObject<User>("Password can not be empty ");
    }

    return entity;
}
```

I like more this second option than the first one but i don't like that i have to change the method signature to return a different class (EntityObject) than the usual (User).

What is the usual? How is it usually managed?
many thanks

Comment: If both code snippets work as expected, this is a question for CodeReview.

Comment: @jsheeran I doubt its for CodeReview, as it doesn't ask for improvement but for best practices which AFAIK are on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An exception should be used when there is something exceptional happening in the system. For a normal flow and something that is expected to happen you should avoid using exceptions.

Following the good SOLID principals your method should do just one thing. So if it is a method to find user by username and password I would say the best would be to return `null` (or empty optional if using optionals). The reason is not lost. Actually it is pretty clear - there is not such user found with the supplied username and password (this reason includes the problem with empty username and it's the user of the method's fault to supply empty username to a login method). Adding complex logic to the method and additional entities for such things will make your code harder to maintain and to understand. This method's job is not to handle validation anyway.

If that class is used by a website or its some kind of API then they can handle the validation (if username or password is empty).

Answer (score 1):

For me, second options look better. Probably, to know what was the error instead of writing messages in java code, you can create `enum` with possible scenarios and resolve it in the Front-end code, if you really need a message, you can create constructor inside enum to store it. It will simplify support and work with an object in the future. Plus, adding more scenarios will not hurt you much.

Basic version:

```
public class EntityObject<t> {
    //Is used to return the entity or entities if everything was fine
    private t entity;
    //Is used to inform of any checked exception
    private enum auth {
        NO_PASSWORD, NO_USERNAME, USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST, SUCCESS    
    }
}
```

Version with `enum` constructor:

```
public class EntityObject<t> {
    //Is used to return the entity or entities if everything was fine
    private t entity;
    //Is used to inform of any checked exception
    private enum auth {
        NO_PASSWORD("Password cannot be empty"),
        NO_USERNAME("Username cannot be empty"), 
        USER_OR_PASSWORD_DOES_NOT_EXIST("No such username or password exist"),
        SUCCESS("OK");
        public String message;
        public auth(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the second approach is pretty fine. If I were you I would do that.

If you *really* don't want to change the return value, you can add another method that checks if a user can log in:

```
public static final String SUCCESS = "Success"
public String checkLoginError(String username, String password) {
    // do all the checks and return the error message
    // return SUCCESS if no error
}
```

Now the `login` method can then be one line:

```
return getUserPassword(username,password);
```

And you can use it like this:

```
String loginResult = checkLoginError(...);
if (loginResult.equals(SUCCESS)) {
    User loggedInUser = login(...)
} else {
    // do stuff with the error message stored in loginResult
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your problem is stemming from a method which is responsible for multiple concerns.

I'd argue that the `login` method shouldn't be checking whether these values are blank. There is presumably some kind of UI (graphical or not) which is taking a username and password - this should be the layer performing validation on the user input.

The `login` method should only be concerned with whether the given credentials match a user in your system or not. There's only two outcomes - yes or no. For this purpose, you can use `Optional<User>`. It should tolerate the strings being empty as this will never match a user anyway (presumably it's impossible for a user to exist in such a state).

Here's some pseudo-code:

```
void loginButtonPressed()
{
    if (usernameTextBox.text().isEmpty())
    {
        errorPanel.add("Username cannot be blank");
    }
    else if (passwordTextBox.text().isEmpty())
    {
        errorPanel.add("Password cannot be blank");
    }
    else
    {
        login(usernameTextBox.text(), passwordTextBox.text());
        // assign above result to a local variable and do something...
    }
}

public Optional<User> login(String username, String password)
{
    Optional<User> user = Optional.ofNullable(getUserPassword(username, password));
    user.ifPresentOrElse(
        user -> LOGGER.info("Found " + username),
        () -> LOGGER.info("Not found")
    );
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java's `null` values are one of the worst aspects of the language, as you cannot really tell if a method is receiving a null value until it happens. If you are using an IDE (I hope so) you can check if it can control whether you are passing a `null` value where there shouldn't be one (IntelliJ can do this by adding the `@NotNull` annotation to the method's parameters).

Since it can be dangerous, it is better to avoid passing `null`s around, as it will certainly lead to an error as soon as your code gets a bit complex.

Also, I think it would be reasonable to check for `null` values **only if** there is a concrete chance that there could be one.

If you want to express that a value can be present or not, it's better to use `Optional<T>`. If, for some reason, a `null` value could be passed instead of a real value, you could create an utility method whose only concern is to verify that the parameters are correct:

```
public Optional<EntityObject<User>> login(String username, String password) {
    //isNotNull shouldn't be necessary unless you can't validate your parameters
    //before passing them to the method.
    //If you can, it's not necessary to return an Optional
    if (isNotNull(username, password)) {
        //Since I don't know if a password must always be present or not 
        //I'm assuming that getUserPassword returns an Optional
        return Optional.of(new EntityObject<User>(getUserPassword(username,password).orElse(AN_EMPTY_USER)));
    } else {
        return Optional.Empty();
    }
}
```

Anyway, I think that validating the input shouldn't be a concern of the `login` method, even if you don't want to use `Optional`; it should be done in another method instead.